# WPF nested ListView ItemsSource

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, windows-store-apps

I have a following data model:

```
class Item{
  public string Name{get;set;}
  public ObservableCollection<SubItem> SubItems {get;set;}
} 

class SubItem{
  public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

I have a `ListView` that shows an ObservableCollection fine as:

```
        <ListView x:Name="lvResult" Background="DeepPink" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding }" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                        <ListView Background="Black" Margin="8,0,0,0">
                            <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            </ListView.ItemsPanel>
                        </ListView>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

However, I'd like to have a horizontal list of items (the nested ListView) - but I don't know what to set as ItemsSource for the nester ListView.

Comment: You can refer [Databinding for nested collections in XAML (WPF and Silverlight) - WebX - Site Home - MSDN Blogs](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/harryh/archive/2010/06/12/nested-collections-databinding-in-xaml-wpf-and-silverlight.aspx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that outer `ListView` is bound to list of `Item` then inner `ListView.ItemsSource` should be bound to `SubItems` property

```
<ListView x:Name="lvResult" ...>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                <ListView ... ItemsSource="{Binding SubItems}">
```